# Facebook Comment not shown ios swift

Tags: javascript, html, ios, facebook, swift

I've getting the html and javascript from this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

```
var wkWebView: UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 400.0, 500.0))

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let facebookCommentsURL = "<!DOCTYPE html><html> <head> <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"> </head><body> <div id=\"fb-root\"></div><script>(function(d, s, id){var js, fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id; js.src=\"http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=527957123932456&status=0\"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script> <div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\"www.example.com\" data-width=\"470\" data-num-posts=\"5\"></div></body></html>"
    self.wkWebView.loadHTMLString(facebookCommentsURL, baseURL: NSURL(string:"www.example.com"))
    self.wkWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(self.wkWebView)
}
```

I already escape all the html tag in this case..However, the facebook comment view still doesn't come out. Just a blank space to show in my ViewController. What happened to this?

Comment: Can you test this with a normal HTML page that you load? Is the plugin loading in that case? If so, there is probably something wrong with the html or encoding you use directly.

Comment: @Roemer I've changed the html from the previous one..tested in html browser, still not able to show in the webView in iOS...can you try yours in iOS WebView?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer why I can't load in webView. The reason is because I did't add the http:// in front of the URL there, that's why iOS don't recognise it. And I did it finally....